Clear 'draft' text of a very long iMessage
I have managed to paste into a group message thread on iMessage (macOS Sonoma) a large block of text. If I switch to the thread on my Mac, iMessage either freezes (need force-quit) or is at best extremely unresponsive. It now continues to update the thread, which I can use normally from my iPhone. Other message threads are unaffected.
I have tried signing out of iMessage and logging back in: the text reappears. Attempts to delete bit-by-bit in the few seconds I get of responsiveness have failed. The 'draft' must be saved somewhere, which I need to clear - but asking Apple has thus-far failed to help. Where should I be looking to 'kill' this draft text?

Please quit Messages if it's running, then move the folder Library/Messages in your home folder to the Desktop. Relaunch Messages. If it works now and your message threads are repopulated (perhaps after a delay), you can delete the old Messages folder.

Thanks - it turns out that inside there is a directory called Drafts, and removing that zaps all of the text
